# wrapping <li>'s with <a> tags in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to wrap images with a tags inside list items that are part of a slideshow, and having problems getting it to work. does anyone have some input? not sure if once I wrap the image, it will break the javascript code, but I am having a tough time getting it to wrap, or maybe I am way off here... I do just fine creating the mouseover to swap the images, but not sure on wrapping the a tag...any help would be great!

html

```
<div id="container" class="cf">
    <div id="main" role="main">
       <section class="slider">
          <div class="flexslider">
             <ul class="slides">
                 <li class="slide-link-1" data-thumb="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg">
                     <img src="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg" />
                 </li>
                 <li data-thumb="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-2.jpg">
                     <img src="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-2.jpg" />
                 </li>
```

jquery

```
$('.slide-link-1 img').on({'mouseover' : function() {
      $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="',google.com,'"/></a>');  
},
```

Comment: I don't think you want to wrap on mouseover. With nothing to remove the wrapping `<a>` elements, the img nodes would be wrapped over and over again, every time a mouseover event occurred, giving `<a><a><a><a><a><img></a></a></a></a></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of the links like this:

```
var links = [];
links = ['google.com', 'doodle.com', 'booble.com'];
```

Then, count how many elements are above the one you are hovering and use that as an index, wrap on mouseenter, unwrap on mouseleave.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/rs4ad9z4/2/)

```js
var links = [];
links = ['google.com', 'doodle.com', 'booble.com'];

$('li.slide-link > img').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var i = $(this).parent().index('.slide-link');
        $(this).wrap('<a href="' + links[i] + '"></a>');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide-link" data-thumb="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg">
        <img src="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="slide-link" data-thumb="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg">
        <img src="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="slide-link" data-thumb="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg">
        <img src="imgs/landing-page/slider-img-1.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** Hovering twice wrapped the  with another . Now fixed

Comment: Hi Aramil, I attempted your solution and as well, and reacted the same way as the other user's option, just jumps to the next slide when I try to hover. I am using the following as a base. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ I think once the a tags are applied, just shifts to the next slide. works basically the same way if I try to hardcode the a tags in the html.

Comment: I did what you asked, I think the problem is that the script you are using for the slider probably  can't slide <a> elements. I'm not really sure though.

Comment: No problem, try bxslider maybe? you could just slide <li><a><img></a></li>

Comment: hi aramil, I am attempting bxslider, when I apply the mouseenter, the image tends to flicker on and off. so I assume when I am mousing around on the image, the jquery treats that movement as leaving and entering repeatedly?...

Comment: My advise: Use chrome developer console, apply a hover status to the <a> element (or <li> or <img>) and watch the CSS properties, there might be some border, margin or padding changing on:hover.

Comment: got it to work! instead off dynamically wrapping the li tags with anchors using jquery, I went ahead and wrapped the original list items, and the code runs smoothly. the client added a deeper level of interactivity today. while in mouseenter state, he wants me to add additional functionality where if the user hovers over specific part of the image, he wants another part of the image to swap out indicating clickable link. (even though the banner already indicates to do so when hovering...) if you have any ideas off the top of your head, let me know. either way, thanks Aramil!